# Android Studio Gradle Build Error - Joda Time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jodatime, apache-commons-io

I added the latest Joda Time jar into my libs folder and added the library. when trying to run I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Selfies:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    File 1: C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\selfieapp\Selfies\Selfies\libs\commons-io-2.4.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\selfieapp\Selfies\Selfies\libs\joda-time-2.8.1.jar
```

Not too sure what this means and how to fix it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update yout `build.gradle` like this:

```
android {
    ...               
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: That has worked, thank you. Would you mind telling me exactly what the problem was for future reference?

Comment: I think you can find more information [Android Tools Project Site
Android Tools Project Site - New Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude this file with packagingOptions in your build.gradle - but you should also have a look into joda-time-android or even better https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: I am currently using the joda time to work out a user's age from their given date of birth. Are there any guides using ThreeTenABP that will do this? Thanks for the ref!